# Haskell - Return item from custom type

Tags: haskell, types

I'm working on a Haskell problem for a class, and I can't seem to get the syntax right for pulling an item out of a custom type. Here's the type:

```
-- Finite State Machine M = (Q, q0, F, d)

type FSM = ([Int], Int, [Int], [(Int,Char,Int)])
```

And here's a test value I've been working with:

```
testFSM :: FSM

testFSM = ( [ 1, 2, 3 ], 1, [ 3 ], [ ( 1, 'a', 2 ), ( 2, 'b', 3 ), ( 1, 'b', 1 ) ] )
```

I want to be able to pull out each piece of data from the FSM type, but I'm not quite sure on how I would do that. I have tried this:

```
fsmGetQ fsm = [ q | ( q, q0, f, d ) <- fsm ]
```

but if I run that function with the testFSM I get:

```
<interactive>:102:9:
    Couldn't match type `([Int], Int, [Int], [(Int, Char, Int)])'
                  with `[(t0, t10, t20, t30)]'
    Expected type: [(t0, t10, t20, t30)]
      Actual type: FSM
    In the first argument of `fsmGetQ', namely `testFSM'
    In the expression: fsmGetQ testFSM
    In an equation for `it': it = fsmGetQ testFSM
```

I've got a lot of helper functions working for the individual elements, but I can't figure out how to extract them from the type FSM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract like this:

```
fsmGetQ (q, _, _, _) = q
```

Answer (score 1):

The list comprehension expects a list, not a tuple, that's why you are getting this error. In addition to @Sibi's answer, I would suggest you to change your type to something more convenient and readable than a multi-element tuple.

Either use an actual data type (think about creating a nested data type for the last tuple too):

```
data FSM = FSM [Int] Int [Int] [(Int,Char,Int)] deriving (Show)

testFSM :: FSM
testFSM = FSM [ 1, 2, 3 ] 1 [ 3 ] [ ( 1, 'a', 2 ), ( 2, 'b', 3 ), ( 1, 'b', 1 ) ]

fsmGetQ (FSM q _ _ _) = q
```

... or a record:

```
data FSM2 = FSM2 {
    getQ :: [Int],
    getQ0 :: Int,
    getF :: [Int],
    getD :: [(Int,Char,Int)]}
    deriving (Show)

testFSM2 :: FSM2
testFSM2 = FSM2 {
    getQ = [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    getQ0 = 1,
    getF = [ 3 ],
    getD = [ ( 1, 'a', 2 ), ( 2, 'b', 3 ), ( 1, 'b', 1 ) ]}

fsm2GetQ = getQ
```

Comment: Thank you. I would, but the FSM type is defined for the assignment.